# Make enemy turn towards player when near

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am currently creating a Flash game using AS3 and have currently reached the point where the user is able to make the player character move around the stage using the keyboard. I currently have two enemies with unique names being added onto the stage upon compiling the game.

What I am stuck on at the moment is detecting which enemy the player is closest to and making only that enemy rotate and move towards the player.

```
public function updateEnemies(player:MovieClip):void{

    //run a for loop on our array and update every enemy object in there
    for(var i = 0; i < enemyObjectsArray.length; i++){

        var enemy:Object = enemyObjectsArray[i];

        //calculate distance between enemyObject's movieClip and target
        enemy.distanceX = player.x - enemy.myMc.x;
        enemy.distanceY = player.y - enemy.myMc.y;

        enemy.distanceTotal = new  Point(enemy.myMc.x - player.x, enemy.myMc.y - player.y);

        trace(enemy.distanceTotal);

        //sort the array based on the enemy object's "distanceTotal" parameter
        enemyObjectsArray.sortOn("distanceTotal", Array.NUMERIC);

        enemyObjectsArray[0].myMc.rotation = 10;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your Enemy Class a _distance property and access to the _player instance, the distance property of each enemy can be calculated by:

```
_distance = Vector3D(x - _player.x, y - _player.y, z - _player.x);
```

Then, if your enemies are in an Array, you can sort the Array by the distance property:

```
_enemies.sortOn("distance", Array.NUMERIC);
```

The above assumes you have a 'getter' method for _distance on your Enemy Class. The nearest enemy will be either _enemies[0] or _enemies[_enemies.length-1] depending on if the sort is ascending or descending.

This also assumes you're working in 3 dimensions, but in 2D you can use Point instead of Vector3D.

BTW, once you've established which Enemy is closest you can call a method (eg, pursuePlayer) on that instance of Enemy to set it to move toward the Player.
To get the Enemy to check if it is facing toward the Player, I'd recommend using Math.atan2((relative y coordinate), (relative x coordinate)) to get the angle to the Player (note that atan2 uses the y coordinate first, and angle '0' is at '3 o'clock').

Comment: Hi moosefetcher. Thanks for the help and code. I implemented your suggested code and traced out _distance. However since I have two enemies on the stage _distance traces out the X and Y coordinates for both the enemies. I updated my question with the method which I am using to detect the nearest enemies.

Comment: There are 2 reasons it's not working. You will need to sort your enemyObejctsArray from OUTSIDE of the loop that updates them. The other is that you don't have a 'distance' property on each enemy that is accessible OUTSIDE of that loop. You will need to add a distance property to each of your enemy objects.